# How to process XML files

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Im pretty new with XML (although i understand the data structure) and very confused :(. So i started to research on this more thoroughly after completing a recent project (it was time critical so i did what i could  but was pretty painful). Now i want to 'learn' the correct way to go about this so i know for future.

I have a very lengthy XML file. This file has a lot of nodes. In addition if i change the query i would receive a different XML.

So my research led me to use XSD. I need to use this tool to first generate an XSD and then a class to hold the data returned (so i think). I ran the below commands

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>xsd.exe C:/Users/name/Desktop/myFile.xml /l:VB /outputdir:c:/projects/ /classes
```

then i tried to create a class from the XSD produced

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>xsd.exe c:/projects/myFile.xsd /classes /language:VB
```

but got an error "The attribute score is missing". So this left me thinking that i need to research on this further but i was overwhelmed by the number of articles which some were designed to use in 2005 but only got me confused.

1. So how should i process an XML file and create relevant classes (VS 2010 or VS 2013)?
2. Should i need to create an XSD for all XML files or returned XML from web services?
3. Does VS2010 or VS2013 do any of the heavy lifting that i could learn/read up on further?

Please note i have read MSDN and a ton of articles but need a pointer in the right direction to fill in the missing gap. 
I generally use VB .Net and SQL to Linq but i need to understand the foundation of processing an XML file and how it should be done if the returned XML contains different nodes. I have read up on XMLSerialiser but there seems to be different ways to handle this if using XML to Linq.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I give you example about insert database mysql to xsd, but the first you must create table from xsd file. for example give the name of table inside your xsd is employee, fill that table with code and name.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module dbase
    Public odm As New MySqlConnection
    Public odmc As New MySqlCommand
    Public dt As New DataTable
    Public adap As New MySqlDataAdapter

    Public Sub connect_to_sql()
        Dim coba As String

        If odm.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            coba = "server='localhost';port=3306;uid='root';pwd='';database=arthur;"
            odm.ConnectionString = coba
            odm.Open()
        End If
    End Sub
Public Sub rssql(ByVal sql As String)
    dt.Reset()
    adap = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, odm)
    adap.Fill(dt)

End Sub
  End module
```

This code insert data table to xsd file. Before you create this code insert to your form is dataset component, and than connect to xsd file has been created.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Manform()
        koneksisql()
         rssql("select code,name from employee")
     For i as integer=0 to dt.rows.count-1
        Dataset11.employee.rows.add(new object(){dt.rows(i)(0),dt.rows(i)(1)})
        Msgbox(Dataset11.employee.rows(i)(0))
     Next

    End Sub
End sub
```

If u using xml some times report can't load from xml file.

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt really tell me how i would generate a class or answer my questions to clear any confusion. Thanks again for trying.